# Update the user information by using PHP (android app)

Tags: php, android, sql

I successfully registered on my android app. But somehow, I really want to update the user information I registered by using PHP. But, I failed. What is the problem with this code I worked on.

```
<?php

    $host = 'example.com';
    $user = 'username';
    $pass = 'password';
    $db = 'database';

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    if (!$con) {
      printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }

    $query ="UPDATE user_info VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; // make this query into "update query"
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

    if($statement === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($link)); }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isssss" ,$UserID, $LastName, $FirstName, $Username, $EmailAddress, $Password);

    $LastName = $_POST["LastName"];
    $FirstName = $_POST["FirstName"];
    $Username = $_POST["Username"];
    $EmailAddress = $_POST["EmailAddress"];
    $Password = $_POST["Password"];

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

By the way, I completed this problem by simplifying the problem.

Comment: You should definitely remove the connection informations !

Comment: @Alex Choi Remove connection information immediately and then update database username and password. Never ever share these sensitive information publicly.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the values of variables BEFORE bind them :

```
<?php
//I remove your credentials
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if (!$con) {
  printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

$query ="UPDATE user_info SET lastname = ? AND firstname = ? AND username = ? AND emailaddress = ? AND password = ? WHERE userid = ?"; // make this query into "update query"
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

if($statement === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($link)); }

$LastName = $_POST["LastName"];
$FirstName = $_POST["FirstName"];
$Username = $_POST["Username"];
$EmailAddress = $_POST["EmailAddress"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, $LastName, $FirstName, $Username, $EmailAddress, $Password, $UserID);

mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
```

**EDIT** `$UserID` is not defined. And your UPDATE statement was complety false